# MVC model binder: Which <input> attribute is compared with input parameter of action method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

as per my knowledge goes Model binder will iterate though all primitive parameters of an action method and then it will compare name of the parameter with each key in the incoming data (http post data). When match is found, corresponding incoming data will be assigned to the parameter.

Now my question is among all `<input>` attribute values(name, value) which one is compared and assigned to method parameter ?

View:

```
<input type="submit" name="BtnSave" value="Save Employee" />
<input type="button" name="BtnReset" value="Reset" onclick="ResetForm();"/>
<input type="submit" name="BtnCancel" value="Cancel" />
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult SaveEmployee(Employee employee, string BtnSubmit)
    {
        switch (BtnSubmit)
        {
            case "Save Employee":
                return Content (employee.EmployeeName + "," + " " + employee.Designation + "," + " " + employee.DateOfBirth);

            case "Cancel":
                return RedirectToAction("EmployeeForm");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Now the `BtnSubmit` will be compared to which attribute? name or value ?

Comment: A form posts back only the name/value pairs of its successful controls. If the name of the control matches the name of a parameter (or model property), it will be set with the value of the control

Comment: @StephenMuecke see the example; name or value what will be compared with BtnSubmit ?

Comment: as far as I'm aware the values of buttons are not posted back from a form. They are not counted as controls in that sense. That's nothing to do with MVC per se, just the way HTML forms work. Post back your form and watch the request body in your browser's dev tools, or in Fiddler. You'll see the contents of the post request and I would be surprised if it contained anything related to the button/submit controls. If you want an extra value, add a hidden field.

Comment: Your parameter is named `BtnSubmit` so if you want to post the value of a subit button, then that button also needs to be named `BtnSubmit` (but what would be the point of that - you only have one button which does an actual submit). What is the point of posting your form to a controller when its a cancel action. Just make it a link that redirect to `EmployeeForm()`

Comment: @ADyson - the values of submit buttons are posted when they are clicked.

Comment: @StephenMuecke ok thanks for the tip. Nonetheless as you pointed out, his button names don't match anyway

Comment: @ADyson: That's incorrect. HTML button elements *are* posted if they have `name` attributes. You also have to add a `value` attribute, of course, if you want the post data to actually have some value, though, but even without that, the button's `name` would still be in the post data, just with a null value. The OP is using `input`s of type "button" here, anyways, so definitely any input will be posted, regardless of its type.

Comment: @ChrisPratt sorry yes I've already acknowledged that as Stephen has pointed out. my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of the HTML control type, the `name` attribute always determines what property or action parameter the modelbinder will bind to, and the `value` attribute always will be the value that property or action parameter will be set to.

However, here, you have an action parameter named `BtnSubmit` and no actual input in your HTML with that same name. Therefore, the value will always be `null`, since that's the default value for a `string` type.

Likely, what you're looking for here is something more like:

```
<input type="submit" name="BtnSubmit" value="Save Employee" />
<input type="button" name="BtnReset" value="Reset" onclick="ResetForm();"/>
<input type="submit" name="BtnSubmit" value="Cancel" />
```

Notice that the two inputs of type "submit" both have the same `name` attribute and that name matches your action param. In this way, they'll act sort of like a radio. Whichever one is clicked will actually post its value. In other words, if the user clicks the one that reads `Save Employee`, then the value of `BtnSubmit` in your action will be `Save Employee`. Otherwise, if the other one is clicked, the value will be `Cancel`.

Also, FWIW, there's actually a `reset` type, so your reset button should be `type="reset"`, not `type="button"`. You might not even need your JavaScript `ResetForm` function at that point. In either case, the value of this button will never be posted, so there's no point in it having a name.